# ng --version shows <error> for Angular version number and some packages

Tags: angular

when trying to retrieve the information about my Angular package, i got the below `<error>` both for Angular version, one package and typescript :

```
$ ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 12.1.3
Node: 14.17.3
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13
OS: win32 x64

Angular: <error>
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1201.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            12.1.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.1.3 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    12.1.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             12.1.3 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.6.7 (cli-only)
typescript                      <error>
```

I've tried uninstall / install again both node.js, npm, angular/cli. Nothing works ! still the error keeps coming back. Any idea on your side ?

Comment: delete node modules folder and then run `npm install`

Comment: running this in `git bash`?

Comment: @naveen yes, running this in git bash

Comment: I have the same problem but, none of the solutions worked for me :(

Comment: @7heViking did you found any solution then ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the problem were actually not angular but some other dependent packages that had conflicting versions.

Answer (score 6):

Delete your node_modiles and your package-lock.json:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
```

Then install all packages again:

```
npm install
```

And if that doesn't help try to reinstall the angular devkit:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when trying to run the last command in git bash,  it got stuck in the middle ... :/

Comment: If you got to the "npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular" part without errors that you probably don't need the last command although you should get an error or get stuck in the process.

Did this problem remain? Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

i solved this using the standard registry using `npm config delete registry` and after that i could install angular globally and then install the dependencies with npm i

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 12.2.17
Node: 16.10.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 7.24.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 12.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.17
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.17
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.17
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.17
@angular/cli                    12.2.17
@schematics/angular             12.2.17
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall that specific package `npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular` ,then recheck `ng v` and run `npm i`.

```
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1202.18
@angular-devkit/core         12.2.18
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.2.18
@angular/cli                 12.2.18
@schematics/angular          12.2.18
rxjs                         6.6.7
typescript                   4.3.5
```